# discord.py DM the owner

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So hello guys here is the problem I want my bot to DM me when joins a server, currently, I'm using this code which doesn't work but it doesn't give me any errors either.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  print(f"bot has joined {client.guild.name} and we have {len(client.guilds)} servers") 
  user = discord.User(my_user_id)
  await user.send(f"bot has joined {client.guild.name} and we have {len(client.guilds)} servers")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove client object from current guild

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  print(f"bot has joined {guild.name} and we have {len(client.guilds)} servers")
  user = discord.User(my_user_id)
  await user.send(f"bot has joined {guild.name} and we have {len(client.guilds)} servers")
```

Comment: I did still the same. it doesn't do anything. no action no error

Answer (score 0):

`User` objects are not meant to be manually created, i.e. doing `discord.User(my_user_id)`. You need to acquire them from your Client/Bot instance.

```py
user = client.get_user(my_user_id)
await user.send(...)
```

Note that [`get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) is dependent on the member cache, so this will require the members intent. The alternative method is using [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user) which makes an API call to get the user object.

Comment: ok i'll try that but why `
print(f"bot has joined {guild.name} and we have {len(client.guilds)} servers")
` doesn't work either ?